# Average Growth Rate for Year 1 across 5 groups

Tags: time-series, mean

I have a question that pertains to time series or more likely pertains just to simple math.

Lets suppose that I am measuring the number of online visitors to 5 websites on a monthly basis, so I have this data for the months of Jan - Dec.

What I want to understand is "What is average **yearly** growth rate for the websites?"

That is, imagine I am doing something to these websites and I want to say to someone that these the 5 websites, which are representative of some population, on average will give a website a x% **yearly** growth rate in visitors in the first year.

Since I have measured this for 12 months for each website, finding the growth rate in visitors for one website would be the standard (t(month12) - t(month 1))/t(month 1). If wanted to find the **yearly** average growth rate across all 5 websites, what would I do? Would it be safe to average the **yearly** growth rates? I am not looking for an extremely formal method for this. I just wanted to know if there are in dire dangers in doing this when trying to get a genereal reflection of the **yearly** growth rate across the 5 website. Hopefully that makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: If you wanted to find the growth rate of your web site, you do not want an average.  You will want to do a linear regression on your points for each individual website, the slope of which will be the average increase in visitors/month.  From those slope coefficients you can get an idea of how fast your traffic is growing. This will also allow you to tentatively predict future growth and factor in other things that may change your readership.

Comment: So months on x axis and visitors on y axis? Therefore, its going to look like I have 12 vertical lines? Run a regression through that?

Comment: You're going to have 12 points, hopefully increasing. You run a linear regression through those 12 points.  For example, if your monthly readerships were (0, 0, 0, 1, 5, 15), your slope would be 2.6.  I did that in R but you can use online tools as well.  This will also give you the fit of your line (R2) as well as the P value of your regression.  You can also add in covariates to see if monthtly temperature affects your readership, or anything else you can imagine. But yes, readership on y and months on x.

Comment: Okay, but the general question I want to answer is the following "What is the average growth rate for the year across the 5 websites in terms of visitors?" That means I would have 60 points. I just want a one number as summary of the growth rate over the course of a year.

Comment: Yep! If you add up the points for each month to get a total number of views per month for all sites (giving you 12 data points), then regress those points, the slope coefficient will be the average number of new viewers looking at any one of your sites per month.

Comment: It depends on what you want the summary to mean. If it is to give the reader a sense of a typical growth rate, consider reporting the median (middle) value.  If it is to reflect overall growth across all sites, then no fixed average may be appropriate. To appreciate this, suppose one site went from 1 visitor/day to 2 and another from 999 to 998. The two growth rates are 100%/yr and -0.1%/yr while the *total* growth went from 1+999=1000 to 2+998=1000, a change of just 0%. Please, then, edit the question to include a statement of your objective.